# Problems running tests (<androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4> has no zero argument constructor)

Tags: android, testing, gradle, junit4, android-espresso

Recently I upgraded my JUnit 4 runner from androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 to androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.

When I execute the test i get the following error: Test running failed:

`Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'`

The LogCat shows this error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: 
java.lang.Class<androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4> has no zero argument constructor
```

All the imports in the test are correct and I'm not getting any error in the build.

My app gradle look like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4'
    }

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

in place of

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4'
```

Comment: That actually worked thanks! I was using that import as I understood that from here (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/runners/AndroidJUnit4)

Comment: Here's the appropriate link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to module's `build.gradle` file:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:<version>'
```

Comment: This is quite hard to read, not only because it could use some https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Could you rephrase and extend with an explanation how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I imported below code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

it solved my error.